# how to play a rtsp stream with authentication using videoview?

Tags: android, rtsp, android-videoview

When disable the rtsp authentication, videoview works well. But for security issues, authentication can not be disabled. So is there a way to play a rtsp stream with authentication?

Comment: There is no way to do this. Drop it!~

Comment: Using videoview it's not possible, but it's possible to display a video with authenticated RTSP in Android.

Comment: @anthony: how can we display authenicated RTSP in android..?? can yu please explain me?? i need to write same application. and i m stuck at this point

Comment: @NiravBhandari it's not easy, I've spend hours and hours on this. I could help you, but not for free sorry.

Comment: @anthony: ok friend.. no issue..thanks for your presious time...

Comment: @anthony: I would be happy if you porovide me some brief idea about it..i'll do it on myself..

Answer (score 1):

you need to `rtsp://User:Password@Server`

Comment: Even its not working with VLC player build using android-vlc-lib, please suggest how we can pass authentication details (username / password) for rtsp live streaming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can't use VideoView with authenticated RTSP, even with rtsp://User:Password@Server.
It won't work.
It is possible to use authenticated RTSP on android but it's hard and you will have to do a lot of things by yourself.

Comment: can you guide me what i need to do?? i'll do it on my self...thanks in advance

Comment: This kind of answer is not very useful, imagine if everyone on SO would post answers like this. I don't expect the full source code but there should at least be some information about the general approach to solve the problem. For others reading this: there is a possible workaround posted on the following SO page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979818/mediaplayer-rtsp-video-stream-with-authentication (did not test that myself yet)